# How do I centralize reused custom Python functions in AWS SAM?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cli

I've created a AWS Cloudformation Stack with a `template.yaml` file that implements several lambda functions. There are several Python functions that some/all of the lambda functions use. Is there a place that I can store common functions? If you think the answer involves layers please address how to include and use *custom* functions (since the [main workflow for layers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html#configuration-layers-path) supports the usual pip python site-package - I'm curious about reusing my own functions).

my project directory:

```
/lambda_functions
/statemachine
samconfig.toml
template.yaml
```

The Layer zip looks like this

python/lib/python3.8/site-packages

In `site-packages` is where I have my other modules - like `/requests` - which are accessible to the lambda functions (ie. `import requests`). But if I put my own directory in there `/custom_functions` with an `__init__.py` file - lambda functions can not find it.

Comment: There are no custom functions in Python. Also Lambda Layers have nothing to do with `pip`. Just but your code inside a package under the `python` root, zip it, and deploy as a layer. No problem. You even linked the reference.

Comment: What do you call something I define like `def function_name(arguement1, arguement2):`? That's the issue - I'd like to reuse my own functions.

Comment: Yes, that is a function. Now what is the problem with layers?

Comment: How do I `import custom_function`? With Layers I can add the requests library to a Layer and then do `import requests`. But I can't seem to do that with my own `custom_functions.py`

Comment: The requests library is a package. In python, a package is a folder containing a `__init__.py` file. So read up on packages, create your own, and happily import your functions.

Comment: No luck with that approach - lambda can still not access module. Adding a bounty for some explicit instructions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can publish your python libraries internally to [pypi repository](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/formats/pypi-repositories#PyPIRepositories-HostingPyPIRepositories) and add those to the `requirements.txt` for the functions. Also ensure your `pypi repository` proxies any other external libraries you define in the `requirements.txt`. This may be a bit complicated if you already don't have an internal `pypi repository`.

Or you can use a Lambda Layer. Let's look at a simple example for using Layers for Python.

Let's say the folder structure of the layer you want to create is where mylib1 and mylib2 are 2 directories which contains some python code. Also you have some third-party dependencies for the code in mylib1/mylib2 or the code in your Lambda function which is defined in the requirements.txt file.

```
my-layer-1
├── mylib1
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── response.py
├── mylib2
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── response.py
└── requirements.txt
```

With this you can add the following to your SAM template

```
 MyDependencyLayer1:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion
    Properties:
        LayerName: my-dependency-layer
        Description: Dependencies required for my Python lambdas
        ContentUri: my-layer-1/
        CompatibleRuntimes:
          - python3.8
        LicenseInfo: 'Apache License 2.0'
        RetentionPolicy: Retain
    Metadata: 
        BuildMethod: python3.8
```

Add update your function to refer to the Layer

```
HelloWorldFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function 
    Properties:
      CodeUri: hello_world/
      Handler: app.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.8
      Layers:
        - !Ref MyDependencyLayer1
```

Now when you execute `sam build`, it will build both the Function and the Lambda Layer as well.

Now you can import a function `my_response1` defined in `response.py` inside the `mylib1` folder like

```
from mylib1 import my_response1
```

provided the `__init__.py` in the `mylib1` folder has the following line

```
from .response import my_response1
```

[Here](https://github.com/GSSwain/python-lambda-with-layers-sam) is a repo which shows this in action.

The above example keeps the Layer and Function definitions in the same SAM template. You can keep the Lambda Layer code in a different repo with a SAM template and build only the layer in a CI/CD pipeline. To do so, you can also use a `makefile` to build your Lambda Layers if you have any custom requirements like pulling dependencies from an internal artifactory. More information about using a makefile [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/building-custom-runtimes.html) and packaging your code for a layer based on different runtimes [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html#configuration-layers-path).

Comment: This is generally a very good, thorough answer. It has all the components anyone needs: the AWS-side and the Python-side. For me I didn't know about the `from .response import my_response1`. Now that I can import my own reused code - I'll be able to greatly reduce the number total lines!

Comment: Glad, it helped!

Comment: I'm getting Unable to import module 'lambda_handler': No module named 'mylib1'